# Text Clobber in powershell html output

Tags: html, powershell

In resulted html file the output of ping result is clobbered. I want the result to be as displayed from the $ping.

$ping = Ping 192.168.1.1

Convertto-html -body $ping | out-file ping.html

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you show the actual vs. expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hack-ish, but try this:

```
$ping = (ping 192.168.1.1) -replace "<", "&lt;"
(ConvertTo-Html -Body $ping) -replace "<body>", "<body>`n<pre>" `
  -replace "<table>", "</pre>`n<table>" | Out-File "ping.html"
```